# file does not exist error, package.json error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I apparently have an error in my package.json. I want to add a "command" to otherwise correctly written package. I want to have a command to load test data, so I added a line/entry to scripts:

```
"load-test-data": "app.js",
```

If I run my app.js as $node app.js - there is no problem, but $npm run load-test-data tells me:

```
npm ERR! load-test-data: `app.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
```

How can I figure out where npm is looking for files?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your app.js is not cli app it wont run you need to do tell npm to run it with node:

`"load-test-data": "node app.js"`

Comment: thank you for taking a look. it is a cli app. At least, I think that it is. My app.js just prints out some statements with console.log()? do i need to do something special to make a javascript like that a cli app.

Comment: if you're at unix type os you can put this at the top of the file:
`#!/usr/bin/env node`

if you're in windows you have to wrap it with bat file that will call node app.js

if you publish your package to npm and specify a bin in package.json it will make it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

To run it with node app.js. And If you want run this script before run app,you can add  **preinstall ** in script section.